# Reading multiple xml files from one xml file and segregating them to new file through Python

Tags: python, readfile, readline, writefile, file-structure

I've a main file(Dummy File) which points to two XML files(TestFile1 & TestFile2). Each file (TestFile1 & TestFile2) consists of multiple xml files. I'm trying to generate new individual xml files (NewFile1,NewFile2, NewFile3, NewFile4)

Content for DummyFile.txt

```
C:/Python27/TestFile1.xml
C:/Python27/TestFile2.xml
```

Content for TestFile1.xml:

```
STLD 20190717 1234 67889056 826 123 L <TLD logVersion= "1.0"></TLD>
STLD 20190717 1234 67889056 826 124 L <TLD logVersion= "1.0"></TLD>
```

Content for TestFile2.xml:

```
STLD 20190717 1234 67889056 826 125 L <TLD logVersion= "1.0"></TLD>
STLD 20190717 1234 67889056 826 126 L <TLD logVersion= "1.0"></TLD>
```

Below is the python code that I've tried:

```
filepath = 'C:/Python27/DummyFile.txt'
with open(filepath) as fp:
    for j in fp:
        with open(j.rstrip()) as f1:
        #f1 = open(j.rstrip(),"r")
            Lines=f1.readlines()
            cnt=1
            for i in Lines:
                f2=open("NewFile"+str(cnt)+".txt","w")
                f2.write(i)
                cnt=cnt+1

            #f1.close()
            f2.close()
```

Content of NewFile1 that has been generated:

```
STLD 20190717 1234 67889056 826 125 L <TLD logVersion= "1.0"></TLD>
```

Content of NewFile2 that has been generated:

```
20190717 1234 67889056 826 126 L <TLD logVersion= "1.0"></TLD>
```

Using the above implementation I'm only able to generate NewFile1 & NewFile2 with the content of TestFile2. It's not populating the content of TestFile1.

Comment: Where, in your code, the two XML files appear?

Comment: Hello @BogdanDoicin, STLD 20190717 1234 67889056 826 123 L <TLD logVersion= "1.0"></TLD> is one xml file content. I've not included the full xml file content as it is quite large. So what I've tried is that I've create a new file (NewFile1) with the first content (STLD 20190717 1234 67889056 826 123 L <TLD logVersion= "1.0"></TLD>) in it

Comment: @KatelynRaphael You are getting only 2 files since value of variable cnt reset to 1 for each file u read, So all the files created using 1st XML will be replaced by files created using 2nd file. 

Work around, Use different variable that u do not reset variable, will solve this OR use some more unique pattern for NewFile to be created.

Comment: Hello@ShivamSeth, Will there be a better approach to achieve this. Can you share your understanding through code, that would be helpful for me!

Comment: Your code always puts the output from whatever input file is being processed into files with a name formed from `"NewFile"+str(cnt)+".txt"`. This means that when all input files have been processed, the files remaining that are named that way will contain the data from the _last_ input file processed. What names should the files have so that they are unique (based on their associated input file name)?

Answer (score 0):

You are using same `cnt` values for `TestFile1.xml` and `TestFile2.xml`.
So you are generating same output files for them (output of latter overwrites the first one).
You can either:

1. move `cnt` initialization outside your `for` loop
2. add unique string when creating file names like so `f2=open("NewFile"+<unique string>+str(cnt)+".txt","w")`.